# Search field based on multiple parameter

Tags: sql

Can anybody modify this , when i insert Emp. name it go to first search and it does not check other paramete could you plz modify this sp for exact search on based on parameter.

```
--select * from Training_TRNS
--USP_SearchEmployee '','2008-04-18 00:00:00.000','','','','',''
alter Procedure USP_SearchEmployee 
@EmpName varchar(100)=null,
@DateFrom varchar(100)=null,
@DateTo varchar(100)=null,
@CourseName varchar(100)=null,
@JobFunction varchar(100)=null,
@Region varchar(100)=null,
@Status varchar(100)=null
AS

BEGIN
if (@EmpName!='' and @EmpName is not null)
    BEGIN
        select EmpName,convert(varchar,DueDate,101) as  DueDate,SpeCourse_ID as CourseName,
        EmpJobFunction as JOBFunction,EmpRegion as Region,Status
        from Training_TRNS where EmpName like '%'+@EmpName+'%'
    END
ELSE IF  (@CourseName!='' and @CourseName is not null)
    BEGIN
        select EmpName,convert(varchar,DueDate,101) as  DueDate,SpeCourse_ID as CourseName,
        EmpJobFunction as JOBFunction,EmpRegion as Region,Status
        from Training_TRNS where SpeCourse_ID like '%'+@CourseName+'%'
    END

ELSE IF  (@JobFunction!='' and @JobFunction is not null)
    BEGIN
        select EmpName,convert(varchar,DueDate,101) as  DueDate,SpeCourse_ID as CourseName,
        EmpJobFunction as JOBFunction,EmpRegion as Region,Status
        from Training_TRNS where EmpJobFunction like '%'+@JobFunction+'%'
    END

ELSE IF  (@Region!='' and @Region is not null)
    BEGIN
        select EmpName,convert(varchar,DueDate,101) as  DueDate,SpeCourse_ID as CourseName,
        EmpJobFunction as JOBFunction,EmpRegion as Region,Status
        from Training_TRNS where EmpRegion like '%'+@Region+'%'
    END

ELSE IF  (@Status!='' and @Status is not null)
    BEGIN
        select EmpName,convert(varchar,DueDate,101) as  DueDate,SpeCourse_ID as CourseName,
        EmpJobFunction as JOBFunction,EmpRegion as Region,Status
        from Training_TRNS where Status like '%'+@Status+'%'
    END

ELSE IF  (@DateFrom!='' and @DateFrom is not null)
    BEGIN
        select EmpName,convert(varchar,DueDate,101) as  DueDate,SpeCourse_ID as CourseName,
        EmpJobFunction as JOBFunction,EmpRegion as Region,Status
        from Training_TRNS where convert(varchar,DueDate,101) like '%'+convert(varchar,@DateFrom,101)+'%'
    END


Else
    BEGIN
        select EmpName,convert(varchar,DueDate,101) as  DueDate,SpeCourse_ID as CourseName,
        EmpJobFunction as JOBFunction,EmpRegion as Region,Status
        from Training_TRNS
    END

END
```

Comment: if i enter emp Name and date it does not search specific It goes first search and check emp name is not null i want to perform should be check both parameter and search like this
select * from tbl where value = parameter and value=parameter2

Comment: Please could post some DDL and some sample data.

Comment: could you plz tell me your email id so i can send talbe data and script for that so u can implement search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) -- this would work only is this is SQL2005/2008, else nvarchar(4000) 

SET @sql='select EmpName,convert(varchar,DueDate,101) as  DueDate,SpeCourse_ID as CourseName,
        EmpJobFunction as JOBFunction,EmpRegion as Region,Status
        from Training_TRNS where 1=1 '

IF (@EmpName!='' and @EmpName is not null)
    SET @sql=@sql + ' AND EmpName like ''%'+ @EmpName+ '%'''

IF  (@CourseName!='' and @CourseName is not null)
    SET @sql=@sql + ' AND CourseName like ''%'+ @CourseName+ '%'''

IF (@JobFunction!='' and @JobFunction is not null)
        SET @sql=@sql + ' AND EmpJobFunction like ''%'+ @JobFunction + '%'''

IF  (@Region!='' and @Region is not null)
     SET @sql=@sql + ' AND EmpRegion like ''%'+ @Region+ '%'''

IF  (@Status!='' and @Status is not null)
     SET @sql=@sql + ' AND Status like ''%'+ @Status+ '%'''

IF (@DateFrom!='' and @DateFrom is not null)
     SET @sql=@sql + ' AND convert(varchar,DueDate,101) like ''%'+convert(varchar,@DateFrom,101)+ '%'''

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
alter Procedure USP_SearchEmployee 
@EmpName varchar(100)=null,
@DateFrom varchar(100)=null,
@DateTo varchar(100)=null,
@CourseName varchar(100)=null,
@JobFunction varchar(100)=null,
@Region varchar(100)=null,
@Status varchar(100)=null
AS

BEGIN
        select EmpName,convert(varchar,DueDate,101) as  DueDate,SpeCourse_ID as CourseName,
        EmpJobFunction as JOBFunction,EmpRegion as Region,Status
        from Training_TRNS 
        where 
                EmpName = isnull(ltrim(rtrim(@EmpName)), EmpName) or EmpName like '%'+@EmpName+'%'
        and     SpeCourse_ID = isnull(ltrim(rtrim(@CourseName)), SpeCourse_ID) or SpeCourse_ID like '%'+@CourseName+'%'
        and     EmpJobFunction = isnull(ltrim(rtrim(@JobFunction)), EmpJobFunction) or EmpJobFunction like '%'+@JobFunction+'%'
        and     EmpRegion = isnull(ltrim(rtrim(@Region)), EmpRegion) or EmpRegion like '%'+@Region+'%'
        and     status = isnull(ltrim(rtrim(@status)), status) or status like '%'+@status+'%'
        and     DueDate = isnull(@DateFrom, DueDate) or convert(varchar,DueDate,101) like '%'+convert(varchar,@DateFrom,101)+'%'

END
```

Comment: Thanks for you help ..........but it's not giving proper result.
I think there should be some IF condtion.

If i put only job function it gives all data which is not required .